# React Native Uploading image doesn't work on iOS, it works on Android

Tags: image, react-native, redux, axios, form-data

Using `react-native-image-picker` and `react-native-image-resizer` package, I selected image from gallery on device and tried to upload this image.
I used axios multipart/form-data for uploading image to backend server.
Uploading image succeed on Android device, but it was failed on Simulator without any response or error.

Here is my some code. I didn't get any log in console.

```js
let formBody = new FormData();
formBody.append('json', JSON.stringify(userBody));
//userBody is json request

let avatarObject;
    if (avatarUri !== '' && avatarUri !== null) {
      avatarObject = {
        name: 'userImage.jpg',
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        uri: avatarUri
      };
    }
//avatarObject is image object for uploading here

if (typeof avatarObject !== 'undefined') {
      formBody.append('file', avatarObject);
    }

let myRequest = {
      method: 'post',
      url: URL.UPDATE_PERSONAL_DETAILS_With_IMAGE,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Accept-Encoding': Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'gzip' : '',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
      data: formBody,
    };

return axios
      .request(myRequest)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log('-----updateUserData.Redux.res.data-----', res.data);
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_DATA_SUCCESS});
      })
      .then(() => dispatch(getUserData()))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('-----updateUserData.Redux.err-----', err);
        dispatch({type: UPDATE_USER_DATA_FAILURE, error: err});
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

if your application crash this line will not work for you
add this line to your request header object.

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`